# Setting a Criteria to either value or to Null

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database where I have a form that shows quality assessments. I want the users to be able to click a checkbox (flgFailed) that will show them only failed QA's. The failed Fieldname is MovedToResolution which is a checkbox and a 0 is a Fail. If this isn't checked I would like them to see all QA's regardless of their Failed status. I based on a web search I tried an IIF statement as below...

```
IIf([Forms]![MainMenu]![ManagersMenu].[Form]![flgFailed]=0,[MovedToResolution] Is Null,[MovedToResolution]=False)
```

...in the Field name with <>False in the Criteria for this Expression.

But I'm not getting any records when I run the query regardless if flgFailed is checked or not. When I run the query without this expression, it runs fine. Ive also tried replacing the value for True/False with -1/0 but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes/No fields are never Null. They are -1 or 0. So if you want all records, need to remove the condition or try LIKE with * wildcard. I never use dynamic parameterized query. Review http://allenbrowne.com/NoYesNo.html and http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Sorry I want the query criteria to be null, not the checkbox field. I'm trying to get a query that I can SOMETIMES limit to just failed responses. When I want to see both true and false records, I need the criteria in the query to be null.

Comment: The operator (=, LIKE, Is Null etc) cannot be dynamic. Your IIf conditional is attempting to change the operator. The answer by Olivier looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ManagersMenu` is a subform control and that the expression `[Forms]![MainMenu]![ManagersMenu].[Form]![flgFailed]` really returns the desired value, I would change the criteria expression to

```
Not [Forms]![MainMenu]![ManagersMenu].[Form]![flgFailed] Or [MovedToResolution] = 0
```

But in the criteria expression `MovedToResolution` refers to the table column and not to the `CheckBox`, therefore whether to test for `0` or `False` depends on the type of the column. If it is declared as Integer number then `0` is okay; however, if it is a `Yes/No` column, then use

```
Not [Forms]![MainMenu]![ManagersMenu].[Form]![flgFailed] Or Not [MovedToResolution]
```

Boolean expressions should be combined with `And` and `Or`. `IIf` is to return other types of values based on a Boolean expression.

Comment: Flag failed can be one of two values though. It's either -1 if I  want to limited it to the failed only or 0 if I don't. MovedtoResolution also refers to the Query column that itself refers to the table column. I want to change the criteria not the value of the field in the table.

Comment: This doesn't change any values, it is a criteria. The right syntax depends on the data type of the columns.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand this, Because this is the criteria expression, the second phrase (it is a yes/no check box) is saying Moved to resolution can be either: not the value of the form control OR not the value of the record of MovedToResolution?

Comment: It means either `flgFailed` is not checked OR `MovedToResolution` is not `True` or `-1` (depending on the data type of the table column).